# Format Cells if greater than "value of the cell"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Values of K11–K13 are variables. On the Conditional formatting, I want to use the output from those cells in the "Greater than" function. Typing `=k11` doesn't work. I'm not really sure on how to do it. I hope you guys can help.

[image: help]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to type `=k$11` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to freeze it (lock it down) with **`$`** symbol to turn it full static because Conditional formatting rules are by default arrayformula types meaning if you set a range lets say of ten cells **A1:A10** and enter formula **`=A1=1`** then it auto searches for value **`1`** in every cell of that range. If you set it on just **`=A1`** then cell **A1** is compared to cell **A1**, **A2** is compared to **A2**, **A3** to **A3**, etc. So in order **A3** to always look for **A1** you need to lock down the row like **`=A$1`**.

Therefore, in your case try:

```
=$K$11
```